# c# Objectlistview remove object with index

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I have a question about an issue. I'm using [this](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) ObjectListView in my project. I know the conpect about this listview so I don't use the regular Listview.Items instead I use the objects. As for my question, I wan't to remove an item from my listview for this I normally use this:

```
mainForm.lvPlaylist.BeginUpdate();
mainForm.lvPlaylist.RemoveObjects(PIList);
mainForm.lvPlaylist.EndUpdate();
```

Now this works. I put 1 object inside PIList and give it to RemoveObjects method and it removes that object. But right now I have 2 different exe and one of them sends the row object to another one with same variable values except 2 variable. There are 2 variables I store datetime inside and when 1 of my exe says to second one "Okay here are the values create your row object but I can't give you my creationTime" the second one creates the object and adds it inside of its own list. But when it comes to remove because of the difference of this variable my second exe can't find the item inside of its own list and cant delete.

My question here is: Can I somehow remove this variable value from being checked? or can I remove an object with index somehow? I searched but couldn't find

EDIT: I made a workaround for my problem. Added index property to my model and when I send the row object to my second application I use this index property to re-create the object list and then pass the newly created object list to my delete method and it works. I've tried IEquatable interface but it did not worked. Till I found a better solution I'll continue with this workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The control uses `Equals()` to determine if two model objects are "the same".

Just implement `Equals()` (and of course `GetHashCode()`) and it work as you expect.